# NCURSES doesn't show scrollbars in elementryOS terminal

Tags: c, linux, scrollbar, ncurses

I've been using `NCURSES` library for my assignment, but there is one big problem with it.
I can't make it to show the scrollbars on the terminal window. I've tried anything I found [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) but none of them seems to work.
I found this code portion in StackExhcange but even this doesn't show schrollbars.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
int i = 0;

initscr();

scrollok(stdscr,TRUE);

while(i<500) {
    printw("%3d - lots and lots of lines flowing down the terminal\n", i);
    ++i;
    refresh();
}

getchar();

endwin();
return 0;
}
```

Is it a problem with elementaryOS because I've heard it's been modified.

Comment: When you say "scrollbar" do you mean the scrollbar of the actual terminal window itself, or a text-redered scrollbar inside the window?

Comment: the scrollbar of the actual terminal window itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- The terminal description is probably using the [xterm *alternate screen* feature](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite).  Some terminals don't display scrollbars when using the alternate screen because scrolling is disabled.  For instance, VTE, which is the *real terminal* you're using by default has (hardcoded) behavior in this mode to translate your scrolling into up/down cursor keys.
- OP expects curses applications to display scrollbars.  They don't, unless the application simulates scrollbars.

For example, [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) does the latter.  Here's an example:

[image: screenshot of dialog with simulated scrollbars]

Comment: so what your saying is if i want scrollbars, i've to simulate them myself?

Comment: Based on your comments, the first suggestion I made seems more likely.